# Is it possible to combine density plots of two separate variables with ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis, density-plot

I feel like I've searched everywhere for this but essentially I have time series data of multiple numeric variables and I wanted to create one single plot that has then density function of two or variables on it.

So essentially I have:

```
df %>% ggvis(~y1) %>% layer_densities()
df %>% ggvis(~y2) %>% layer_densities()
```

but if I do something like:

```
df %>% ggvis(~y1) %>% layer_densities() %>% layer_densities(~y2)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    object 'y2' not found

I feel like this shouldn't be too difficult but I can't figure it out, I don't think I am supposed to use group by because these are two seperate variables with no similar factors or characteristics. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work-around by reshaping your dataset so you have a grouping variable in one column and the values of both columns you want to plot in another.  I do the work via `melt` from *reshape2*.

```
library(reshape2)
df2 = melt(df, measure.vars = c("y1", "y2"))
```

Once you do that you can use `group_by` to get a separate density layer for each variable.

```
df2 %>% group_by(variable) %>% 
    ggvis(~value) %>% 
    layer_densities()
```

Comment: Ahh cool thanks that worked! I presume I could just add more variables to the measure.vars vector to get more factors. Thanks!

Comment: @Imconfused Yep, exactly.  Just put all the variables that are currently in columns that you need in rows as `measure.vars`.

Answer (score 0):

in ggplot you can set color = "your time variable" in aes() to get this density